# I want to install git-secret on a windows machine

Tags: git-secret

I found the command to install git-secret as 'chocolatey install git-secret' or 'scoop install git-secret' in a power shell. Both of the commands are giving errors as manifest not found. Is there any command with which I can install git-secret? Please help.